# Building RPMs: ask rpmbuild to follow symlinks in spec

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to create RPM out of binaries/libraries without source (source is not available to me). My package structure looks like this:

```
Prefix: /pkg/

%file
/pkg/bin
/pkg/lib
```

Everything under bin and lib are really just symlinks to some other locations. But I still want to keep this simple structure **with actual files** when I install it. How do I tell rpmbuild to follow symlinks in %file directive?

I tried the above but when I installed the rpm, it installed symblinks, not the actual files.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

`rpmbuild` will include symlinks as part of a package; there's no way to tell `rpmbuild` to package the *target* of the symlink rather than the symlink itself. The best way to avoid this problem is to put the files you want to package into the buildroot rather than putting symlinks into the buildroot. `rpmbuild` has this behavior for two reasons:

- to make package building a consistent, reproducible process (the contents of the target of a symlink are likely to vary across build hosts)
- to make it easy to include symlinks in packages

Answer (score 0):

Use `cp -L` to copy the real files and convert symbolic links to the real files they point to to your RPM BUILDROOT, eg.

```
%install
cp -RL ./mylinkdir ${BUILDROOT}
```

You can make it your install step.